# Extracting columns from a text file with no delimiters

Tags: text-processing

I have a large text file which is basically a stream of data all pretty much compressed together for each row. I've been asked to look into the failure of certain data in some columns. The data is not delimited in any way. I do however have a list of "column" lengths and comments on whether there's relevant data in each "column".

I'd use Excel, but the limit of Excel to delimit by columns is restricted to 1000 characters per row, and each row goes well beyond this. A number of these fields have strings of 30 spaces that act as filler and there's at least a good 15 or so of these... I'm hoping to parse these designated "empty" fields out.

What I need is a way that I can feed my file in and with an array that I can provide which has the column lengths and maybe a marker like "X" to ignore the respective columns I want to ignore, have it spit out a new file with delimiters, which I can then feed back into Excel for analysis.

For example if I had a file with a row like `aaaaaabbbbbccccdddddeeeffffff` and I feed this file in with an array of `[6 5 4X 5 3X 6]` it would spit out a file with `aaaaaa^bbbbb^ddddd^ffffff` in that row.

Is there a way this can be done with `grep`, `awk` or `sed`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want `^` to be the exact delimiter in resulting rows?

Comment: It was an arbitrary character I used but that would be fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU awk, you can specify explicit fieldwidths e.g.

```
$ printf 'aaaaaabbbbbccccdddddeeeffffff\n' | 
    gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="6 5 4 5 3 6" -v OFS="^" '{print $1, $2, $4, $6}'
aaaaaa^bbbbb^ddddd^ffffff
```

Starting with version 4.2, you can skip characters using a `n:m` syntax e.g.

```
printf 'aaaaaabbbbbccccdddddeeeffffff\n' |
   gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="6 5 4:5 3:6" -v OFS="^" '{$1=$1} 1'
aaaaaa^bbbbb^ddddd^ffffff
```

(the `$1=$` just forces re-evaluation of `$0` with the specified fieldwidths).

See for example [The GNU Awk User's Guide: 4.6 Reading Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html)

Comment: This is closer to what I had in mind... Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Short **`cut`** command approach:

Sample `input.txt` contents:

```
aaaaaabbbbbccccdddddeeeffffff
wwwwwwddddd111133333xxxaaaaaa
ffffff00000sssszzzzz000rrrrrr
```

---

The job:

```
cut -c 1-6,7-11,16-20,24-29 --output-delimiter=^ input.txt
```

- `-c` - to select only characters
- `1-6,7-11,16-20,24-29` - consecutive ranges of character positions, flexibly adjustable
- `--output-delimiter=^` - output field delimiter, you can adjust it to whatever you want

---

The output:

```
aaaaaa^bbbbb^ddddd^ffffff
wwwwww^ddddd^33333^aaaaaa
ffffff^00000^zzzzz^rrrrrr
```

Comment: [Fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).  The numbers `-c 1-6,7-12,17-22,26-31` don't match the output, for example with those numbers the first output line would be:  `aaaaaa^bbbbbc^ddddee^ffff`.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing your exact input and desired output, but...

```
sed -e "$(
  printf '%d\n' 6 5 4 5 3 6 |
    awk '
      {
        f[NR] = f[NR-1] + $1
      }
      END {
        for (i=NR; i>0; i--) {
          printf "s/./&^/%d\n", f[i]
        }
      }
    '
)" infile.txt | cut -d^ -f1,2,4,6
```

Untested.  No bugs, I promise.  ;)

---

Okay, I tested.  I was missing the end brace for `END`.  No other bugs.  Works perfectly on example input.  Output is:

```
aaaaaa^bbbbb^ddddd^ffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of [RomanPerekhrest's `cut` answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399286/165517), with column array parser, including `X` suffixes to show how many columns to skip.

Load array `$n`, and make a function to parse array into numbers for `cut -c`:

```
n=(6 5 4X 5 3X 6)
col_array() { j=$(h=0; 
                  for f in $@; do 
                      g=${f/[Xx]};
                      i=$((h+1));
                      h=$((h+g));
                      [ $g = $f ] && echo -n $i-$h,
                  done;) ; 
              echo ${j%,}; }
```

The file *input.txt* contains:

```
aaaaaabbbbbccccdddddeeeffffff
wwwwwwddddd111133333xxxaaaaaa
ffffff00000sssszzzzz000rrrrrr
```

Use `col_array()` with `cut`:

```
cut -c $(col_array  ${n[@]}) --output-delimiter=^ input.txt
```

Output:

```
aaaaaa^bbbbb^ddddd^ffffff
wwwwww^ddddd^33333^aaaaaa
ffffff^00000^zzzzz^rrrrrr
```

There's no strict need for an array, since `col_array()` parses its parameters:

```
cut -c $(col_array 3 5X 7) --output-delimiter=^ input.txt
```

Output:

```
aaa^bbbcccc
www^ddd1111
fff^000ssss
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, one could write (using `_` as delimiter):

```
sed "$(echo s/./\&_/{29,23,20,15,11,6}\;)"
```

But this means to sum up the absolute positions from the column widths. TO directly use the widths, we need some ugly escaping for the command substitution:

```
sed -E "s/./&_/6;$(echo s/.\*_\(.\)\{{5,4,5,3,6}\}/\&_/\;)"
```